# What does the 'throws' keyword on a method mean?

Tags: java, methods

So if I am looking at this piece of code:

```
public Plugboard(String wires) throws InvalidPlugboardWiresException
```

What exactly does the `throws InvalidPlugboardWiresException` mean?

Comment: the method can throw a `InvalidPlugboardWiresException` or any of its subclasses (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html)

Answer (score 0):

It declares that this method may throws InvalidPlugboardWiresException exception.
Here is a description on how to throw and catch exceptions in methods: [enter link description here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

This is information that this constructor can throw `InvalidPlugboardWiresException`. You should handle this exception in place where you are using it.

Remember that the most dangerous thing you can do is catch an exception and do nothing with it.